# Задача определить идёт ли массив от меньшего к большему. Проблема кода если ставить в середине, элемент больше за предыдущий, то он сработает не так

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = [1,20,23,43,50,655,701]
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
        console.log('Массив идёт от меньшего к большему')
        break
    } else {
        console.log('Массив не идёт от меньшего к большему')
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [1, 20, 23, 43, 50, 655, 701];

let increasing = true;
for (let i = 0; increasing && i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] >= arr[i + 1])
    increasing = false;
}
console.log(`Массив${increasing? ' ' : ' не '}идёт от меньшего к большему`);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, всё работает, можно пожалуйста объяснить ошибку?

Comment: @Denbez Вы что, не видите, чем отличается мой код от Вашего?

Comment: Можно еще убрать одну лишнюю итерацию `i < arr.length - 1`

Comment: @Denbez И я уже отвечал Вам на этот же самый вопрос. - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1274843